# Page is not jumping if window.onhashchange is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I am using hashchange event to ask a confirmation dialog box saying that the data in the current page will be lost, if moved.

I've implemented like this:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    if(window.confirm("Do you really want to close?")){
    }
};
```

This event is triggered correctly. But the page is not changing if the user clicks yes. What do I need in the {...}?

Comment: What does "getting jumped" mean?

Comment: getting jumped, I meant the new page is not loading.

Comment: Your code is not complete - what goes inside the  {} if the user confirms?

Comment: I want to move to the new page, if "yes" is clicked in the confirmation dialog box. The user will be in the same page, if "no" is clicked. I don't know how to do this. Hence left it as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```js
window.onhashchange = function() {
  if (window.confirm("Do you really want to navigate?")) {
     location.hash = location.hash; // or set the hash elsewhere and change here
  }
};
```